# Regular expression, get word after, and word after # and that if the word was 'the'

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the word that's after the word '*from*'

```
from+\s+(\w+)
```

only if that word is '*the*' then i would like to **also** get the word after that.

Is this possible with a regex, or does that need to be coded with `equals()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from\s+(the\s+)?(\w+)
```

Is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from\s+(the\s+\w+|\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible : `from\s+(?:the\s+)?(\w+)`